# change language setting in iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a table view and inside 2 static group, that one of them contain language, I want to have 2 language english and french in my setting for my application,that when user chose english the whole setting change to english and when user chose french everything change to the french language would you please help me,I saw some sample but I don't know how can I set and where should I set the code,how should I connect the code to my check mark cell!

Thanks in advance!

here is picture for my setting :

[image]

Comment: are you familiar how the application can be localized? if no... here are some [basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171-SW1).

Comment: @holex thanks I localized my application,but do you know how can i check it via simulator?

Comment: change the language settings on the device's menu at `Settings` -> `General` -> `Language` section.

Comment: @holex I change it but nothing changed in my app ;(

Comment: then you've implemented the localisation wrongly. :( have the `Localizable.string` files separated in the correct folders? how do you load the localised string from these files for the current language?

Comment: @holex I will do it again! but can I change the language from my application like the picture above? thanks in advance!

Comment: you can change the language in you application, just the Apple's build-in localisation service is not good for you then. you should write the own localisation algorithm in your code. You should store the texts of the all languages somehow (the `plist` file look the best for it), and for every UI element you have to check manually which language is the active one (the best way for this in the `-viewWillAppear:` method), and for the selected language you should load and show the current text on the UI, before you show it for the user. the logic is simple, it is a **huge** slave-work.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you get language code from this code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
```

2) Make the Localizing strings file

3) use this  `NSLocalizedString(@"WelcomeKey", @"")`

Example:

```
 NSString *example=@"";


    if([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"en"])
    {
      example =  NSLocalizedString(@"WelcomeKey", @"Engliah");
    }

    else {
      example =  NSLocalizedString(@"WelcomeKey", @"french");
    }
```

Comment: follow this link http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/11/localizing-iphone-apps.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Give outlets to all your text objects in all your xibs ( labels, textfields ). This will allow you to access them to change their values ( e.g. to change the placeholder of a textfield from "First name" into "Prénom" ).
2. Make a .plist file with keys  and values for english content ( you can use the name of outlets as keys ), and another one for french content.
3. Keep a default value e.g. `myLanguageIndicator` ( in NSUserDefaults ) that will hold your current language, and that will be changed respectively when you set the language.
4. Depending on your default value ( is if "eng" or "fr" ), in every class, in viewWillAppear, set the values of your outlets by reading from the needed .plist file.

Suppose your default language value is "fr". This means you will use fr.plist (or whatever you name it) in viewWillAppear. And "titleLabel" is an outlet for the title label in one of your controllers.

In another default object you keep a dictionary of your fr.plist (google how to load a plist into a dictionary).

Then you say:

```
if ([myLanguageIndicator isEqualToString:@"fr"]){
      titleLabel.text = [myFrenchDictionary objectForKey:@"titleLabel"];
   ... ... ...change here all your outlets to french values
   }
   else{
      titleLabel.text = [myEnglishDictionary objectForKey:@"titleLabel"];
       ... ... ...change here all your outlets to english values
   }
```

And when you select the language, just change your default string object `myLanguageIndicator` into `@"fr"` or `@"eng"`, depending on the language you have selected.

Comment: Happens when you want to build apps using nibs and storyboards lol